# Origin of the expression one-two

Tags: expressions, sports

In football, the expression "one-two" (or "give-and-go") means: Player A passes the ball to Player B, who immediately passes it back to Player A.

Why is this called "to play a one-two"? Where does this expression come from? Does it originate from the boxing term "one-two punch"? Or does it originate from somewhere else?

Comment: It also has references in fencing: https://books.google.com/books?isbn=0271010193

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***A give-and-go, or one-two,*** is a fundamental maneuver in many team sports which involves two players passing the ball or puck back and forth. The player who has the ball or puck passes to a teammate and then repositions in order to receive a return pass and a scoring opportunity.

(Wikipedia)

It looks like the expression originated in boxing at the beginning of the 19th century:

> - ***[one-two blow](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/one-two)*** A combination of two blows with the fists, a short left jab plus a hard right cross, usually to the chin : zipping ''one-twos'' to the jaw (1811+)

(The Dictionary of American Slang, Fourth Edition by Barbara Ann Kipfer, PhD. and Robert L. Chapman, Ph.D.)